# How To Change text string color of matching string based on another cell text

Tags: excel, vba, text, colors, matching

Hope all are fine. I google about the above issue but did not find anything matching. So here I am asking the fact. Hope someone helps me to get through.

I am using an auto filter search. In Cell E5 what word do I type, the table of a specific range filtered based on that value of Cell E5.

My table ranges from B8:K1220.
[image]

Now, I want the Text String of E5 and the matching Text string in the Table Range will be Highlighted as Yellow. If the E5 cells have nothing then all range color return to normal.

In Image where In E5 I type "Alex" then the matched Text String in the table Highlighted as Yellow. I want a code like this.

Hope someone help and really appreciate the creation of an amazing code.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but if you just want to color certain cells that have the same value as cell E5, you should use conditional formatting for that

Comment: I think you should add an example to your question, including expected output

Comment: I add an Image editing my original post. Hope you understand my requirements. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Create a conditional formatting rule based on this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A2;$E$5&"*")>0
```

> [Use conditional formatting to highlight
> information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)

Answer (score 1):

### Conditional Formatting

- Select the range `B8:K1220` i.e. use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open the *"Go To"* form and in the text box below *"Reference:"* enter `B8:K1220` and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.
- On the Ribbon, select `Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule` to open the *"New Formatting Rule"* form.
- In the list box below *"Set a Rule Type:"*, select *"Use a formula to determine which cells to format"*. In the text box below *"Format values where this formula is true:"* use the following formula:

  ```
  =SEARCH($E$5,B8)=1
  ```
- After choosing the desired format (not described), confirm with <kbd>OK</kbd> twice.

Comment: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$5,B8))` would highlight also value `D.K. Alexture` and according to image from OP, that cell does not need to be highlighted

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns: Thanks, can't argue with that. Fixed it. The requirement is *"begins with"*, and not *"contains"* as I initially thought.

Comment: Now it's perfect! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of a range using the `.Interior.Color` of a range.  The yellow color for highlighting is 65535.

You can change the color of a range's text using the `.Font.Color` of a range.

```
Private Sub Color()

    Dim MyCell As Range
    Set MyCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
    
    MyCell.Interior.Color = 65535
    MyCell.Font.Color = 0

End Sub
```